# AngularJS - Handling refresh token?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, access-token, http-status-code-401

I'm building a SPA with AngularJS with communication to a service (JAVA).

When user sends his username/pass, service sends back both: Acces token and Refresh token. I'm trying to handle: if I get response with status 401, send back refresh token and then send your last request again. I tried to do that with including $http, but angular doesn't let me include it in this interceptor. Is there any way to recreate the original request with this response parameter I'm recieving?

Something like:

1. I get 401
2. save my request
3. if I have a refresh token send that refresh token
4. on success resend my request
5. on error redirect to /login page

   ```
   'use strict';

   angular.module('testApp')
       .factory('authentificationFactory', function($rootScope, $q, $window, $location, CONF) {

   return {
       request: function(config) {
           config.headers = config.headers || {};
           if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
               config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
           }
           console.log(config);
           $rootScope.lastRequest = config;
           return config;
       },

       response: function(response) {
           console.log($rootScope.lastRequest);
           if (response.status === 401) {
               if ($window.sessionStorage.refreshToken) {

                   //Save, request new token, send old response
                   //if it fails, go to login

                   $location.url('/login');
               } else {
                   $location.url('/login');
               }
           }
           return response || $q.when(response);
       }
   };
   });
   ```

Bonus Question (the main question is more important): There are 2 mobile apps that will also connect to my service, and when I log in from my web app, and few moments later from my mobile app, mobile app takes a new refresh token and my web app's refresh token is valid no more. What would be the best option for dealing with that?

Thank you for your time,
Best regards

Comment: Hi @dyslexisDcuk,
you got any success on that please share with me.
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at this: https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth.

He uses a buffer to replay the requests after authentication.

Comment: Brilliant! Will test it out later and get back to you, thanks a lot :)

Comment: It didn't really answer my question but it did take me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: So, what's yout final solution?

Comment: @DyslexicDcuk Mind posting your solution?

Comment: @mateeyow I'm really sorry but I switched companies a while back and don't have acces to that code any more.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly advise **against** sending and storing refresh tokens on SPAs like Angular.

If you are using session storage or local storage, you are opening a window of opportunity for the this refreshToken to be captured, either by a XSS attack, or by the user leaving the computer unattended.

See [this article](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280827/using-oauth2-in-html5-web-app) for more info.