# CSRF Protection for Refresh Token Cookie in SPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, oauth-2.0, csrf

I am using the Resource Owner Password Credentials OAuth 2.0 flow in a AngularJS SPA. There are several articles ([here](http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/), [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/)..) and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18280827/498298) that explain that we should not store refresh tokens on the (web) client (LocalStorage), but store them encrypted in an HttpOnly Cookie and use a proxy API where we implement the decryption of the refreh token to forward it to the security token service.

Most articles give a hint that we should care about CSRF by using one of the common protection mechanisms. I'm wondering what's the best solution in a Single Page Application.

The Angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection) reference explains the default mechanism how we should counter CSRF: The server has to set a cookie called `XSRF-TOKEN`. This cookie has to be Javascript readable, so that we can set the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` HTTP header in our requests. Is this mechanism sufficient to protect the refreh token scenario?

1. Start the application the first time. No access token nor cookie available, we have to login with username and password. `api/login` gives us an access token that we keep in memory and sets two cookies. The HttpOnly refreh token cookie, and the JS readable `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie.
2. The access token expires. A call to `api/token` validates `XSRF-TOKEN` and uses the token cookie to return a new access token; sets a new refresh cookie
3. Restart the application from `AppCache`. No access token in memory but cookies available. Use `api/token`...
4. Bad guy wants to steal our refreh cookie. A prepared page makes request to `api/token` with our cookies, but no `X-XSRF-TOKEN` HTTP header.

Any serious security issues?

Comment: Well this still doesn't protect you from session/cookie/localStorage hijack. To do that you need to additionally verify last valid access token in step 2 - this will ensure that stolen cookie won't be valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the best way to do this is when server renders index.html with the CSFR token inside and after that you function as standard AngularJS SPA. So the `index.html` is then enriched with CSFR token generated by backend service / framework. SpringSecurity provides nice support for this injecting tokens to the templates.

After that, you can get the token from the template with javascript and set it to all your `$http` requests in headers by using `httpInterceptor`'s, `request` hook. (or cookie)? I don't remember clearly whats the proper way but I am sure it is described in articles you mentioned above)