# Is it possible to use OAuth2 to secure "non-rest" applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, authentication, oauth

We have an application written in ASP.NET MVC which consists of Web (non rest, using razor) and API projects (and some other projects, but that is besides the point now).

Authentication in Web is done using basic forms authentication and authentication in API is done using OAuth2.

Having two ways of authentication in the same application has proven to be somewhat difficult to maintain, so we decided to discard forms authentication and use OAuth2 for both Web and API projects.

In Web project, we would probably have to store OAuth2 tokens in cookies instead of sending them as headers. Is it possible to use OAuth2 to secure "non-rest" applications ? If so, are there some security concerns in doing so?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2015/11/19/using-oauth2-with-soap/

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/253 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280827/using-oauth2-in-html5-web-app

Answer (score 0):

There are some excellent articles on the topics you are interested. These articles explain the details that you are looking for.

1. [Tokens and Cookies](https://auth0.com/blog/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/).
2. [The Ultimate Guide to Mobile API Security](https://stormpath.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-mobile-api-security)
3. [The Most Common OAuth2 Vulnerability](http://homakov.blogspot.com/2012/07/saferweb-most-common-oauth2.html)
4. [Using OAuth 2.0 with the SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/03/oauth-and-the-soap-api.html)
5. [Using OAuth2 with SOAP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2015/11/19/using-oauth2-with-soap/)
6. [ASP.NET WebForms OAuth2 multi-tenant resource and WPF client](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2014/06/08/asp-net-webforms-oauth2-multi-tenant-resource-and-wpf-client/)

These sites will be the starting point. OAuth 2.0 is criticized a lot but the security vulnerabilities that everyone is pointing out is also common in other authentication model. So if those vulnerabilities are addressed in the application then the security issues will mitigate itself.

1. [OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-threatmodel-08)
2. [Common OAuth2 Vulnerabilities and Mitigation Techniques](https://leastprivilege.com/2013/03/15/common-oauth2-vulnerabilities-and-mitigation-techniques/)
3. [SaferWeb: OAuth2.a or Let's Just Fix It](http://homakov.blogspot.de/2012/08/saferweb-oauth2a-or-lets-just-fix-it.html)

But also it must be noted that OAuth2 is not the next generation of OAuth1. You can find an excellent article [here](http://homakov.blogspot.de/2013/03/oauth1-oauth2-oauth.html).

Answer (score 0):

The straight answer would be, yes, it's possible and fine to rely on OAuth 2.0, however, the most honest answer would be it kind of depends and there's more than one way to do it.

### Scenario 1 - Web and API are independent

If your Web application is completely independent and does not act as client of the API, my personal inclination would be to use an OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect flow to get the user authenticated, receive a token that proves their identity and then create a regular session based on cookies. When I say regular session I mean a session that is stored server-side and the cookie only contains a unique identifier for that session.

You can also go ahead and store the actual token in the cookie and go stateless, but I honestly don't see the benefit. In most of the cases a Web application will want to store sufficient information in a session to make the idea of saving it all in a cookie just plain bad. Yes, you can save the access token and then still have session state on the server side associated with that token, but then what would you gain from saving the actual token.

### Scenario 2 - Web is also a client of the API

In this case things may play out differently. Judging from your question your Web application is based on ASP .NET MVC so I will assume that the API calls will take place on the server-side.

I would still go with creating a regular session identifier in a cookie upon authentication instead of saving the actual token, but more important than that you'll have to **decide what to do when the token expires**, you can have the application session last as much as the token allows and then force the user to repeat the whole authentication process to get a new token, but unless your access tokens have a really long lifetime (which is generally frowned upon, not common and also not recommended) this is really bad for user experience.

<sub>My inclination to use a session identifier instead of the token itself is just because with bearer tokens if its not a functional requirement to have the token available to the client then don't do it, as otherwise you're just increasing the impact in case of a breach.</sub>

Personally, on this scenario I would resort to OAuth [refresh token](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/) support to be able to keep refreshing the Web application access token while the user session is active. This way you can easily implement a sliding session that will be active as long as the user is and at the same time use access tokens with shorter lifetimes which reduce the impact of an access token being leaked.

---

Here's some resources for further reading about cookies/sessions and token authentication that may help you get a few different perspectives to support the decision process:

- [Stop using JWT for sessions](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/)
- [Cookies vs Tokens: The Definitive Guide](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/)